# Python binance websocket stream code for getting user data and coin price

Tags: python, websocket, binance, binance-api-client, python-binance

I am trying to get binance futures data from a websocket stream. I've gone through all the binance documentation tried several different python approaches, but don't seem to be successfull.

I am running my code on python-anywhere servers.

I would like to also know, how do you handle reconnections to the stream and for how long do the streams stay open.

The data I need through the websocket:

- SYMBOL TICKER
- FUTURES ACCOUNT BALANCE
- FUTURES OPEN POSITIONS, ORDERS

Any help and directions would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried this sample, but I don't get any response from the stream.

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager

# API keys
API_KEY = '<api_key>'
API_SECRET = '<api_secret>'

# Binance API endpoint
BASE_URL = 'https://fapi.binance.com'

async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key=API_KEY,api_secret=API_SECRET)
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
    ts = bm.futures_socket() # Tried also bm.futures_user_socket()
    # then start receiving messages
    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            print(res)

    await client.close_connection()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to use the [unicorn binance websocket api](https://github.com/LUCIT-Systems-and-Development/unicorn-binance-websocket-api)? I found it easy to handle multiple datastreams from a binance websocket with it, even in concurrent applications. It took me only a few minutes to set up a script that reads kline data for multiple assets:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

"""unicorn-binance_websocket_test.py:

Example script that uses the library 'unicorn_binance_websocket_api' to listen
to multiple streams on a binance websocket.
https://github.com/LUCIT-Systems-and-Development/unicorn-binance-websocket-api
"""
import signal
from typing import Type, Any
from pprint import pprint, pformat
import time
from unicorn_binance_websocket_api import BinanceWebSocketApiManager


def process_new_receives(stream_data: Any,
                         stream_buffer_name: bool = False) -> None:
    pprint(stream_data)


def start_ubwa() -> Type[BinanceWebSocketApiManager]:
    ubwa = BinanceWebSocketApiManager(exchange="binance.com")
    ubwa.create_stream(['kline_15m'], ['btcusdt', 'ethbtc'],
                       process_stream_data=process_new_receives)
    return ubwa


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        ubwa = start_ubwa()
        while True:
            print("###main thread is working###")
            time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Ignore further keyboard interrupts.
        s = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
        # Close WebSocketApiManager (stops all streams + monitoring API).
        ubwa.stop_manager_with_all_streams()
        time.sleep(2)  # Just so stream logger can process last message...
        # Restore keyboard interrupts.
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, s)
    finally:
        print("Exiting program.")
        SystemExit(0)
```

There is also a working example for [reading futures data here](https://github.com/LUCIT-Systems-and-Development/unicorn-binance-websocket-api/blob/master/example_binance_futures.py). Please give it a try and let me know if it works for you.